# If $H,K < G$ and $(G:H), (G:K)$ are finite, prove $(G: H \cap K)$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

If $H,K < G$ and $(G:H), (G:K)$ are finite, prove $(G: H \cap K)$ is finite.

I wrote a proof but I'm not sure whether it works. Please, tell me if it is correct. Here it goes:

If $(G:H)$ and $(G:K)$ are finite, then we can find $n$ distinct $g$'s in $G$ such that $g_{h_i}H,\,i = 1,2, \ldots, n$ produce all the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ and $m$ distinct $g$'s such that $g_{k_j}K,\,j = 1,2, \ldots, m$ produce all the the left cosets of $K$ in $G$. We then form sets based on these elements. What I mean is, we form $\overline{g_{h_1}}, \overline{g_{h_2}}, \ldots, \overline{g_{h_n}}$, so that if $g \in \overline{g_{h_1}}$, for example, these $g$'s are going to produce the same left coset. We do the same for $K$. Consider now the intersection, $H \cap K$. For any $g \in G$, this element belongs to only one of $\overline{g_{h_1}}, \ldots, \overline{g_{h_n}}$ and to only one of $\overline{g_{k_1}}, \ldots, \overline{g_{k_m}}$. We then have at most $mn$ distinct pairs, $\overline{g_{h_j}}$ and $\overline{g_{k_i}}$. In other words, $H \cap K$ has at most $mn$ distinct left cosets, which shows that $(G: H\cap K) < \infty$.

It may be a little confusing. I will clarify the steps more if needed.

$\textbf{Edit to answer Brian Moehring's question}$: I thought a little bit more about the last part of the proof. For example, $g \in \overline{g_{h_1}}$ is going to generate elements of a left coset of $H$, say  $H_1$. But, because we are considering  $H \cap K$, it's going to be contained in $H_1$. Therefore, we need to consider in which of the $\overline{g_{k_1}}, \ldots, \overline{g_{k_m}}$ it belongs to. Let's say it belongs to $\overline{g_{k_1}}$. Then is going to generate elements of the left coset $K_1$. The pair $(\overline{g_{h_1}}, \overline{g_{k_1}})$ then forms the left coset $H_1 \cap K_1$.

$\textbf{Edit (I wrote another proof based on the comments and suggestions made here)}$: If $(G:H)$ and $(G:K)$ are finite, then we can find $n$ distinct $g$'s in $G$ such that $g_{h_i}H,\,i = 1,2, \ldots, n$ produce all the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ and $m$ distinct $g$'s such that $g_{k_j}K,\,j = 1,2, \ldots, m$ produce all the the left cosets of $K$ in $G$. Now, consider the intersection $H \cap K$. For an arbitrary $g \in G$, we have $g(H \cap K) = gH \cap gK = g_{h_i}H \cap g_{k_j}K$ for some $i,j$. From this we can conclude that $(G: H \cap K) < \infty$, because there are only, at most, $mn$ distinct sets of the form $g_{h_j}H \cap g_{k_j}K$.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what does : mean in (G:K)?

Comment: How do the pairs of cosets of $H,K$ relate to the cosets of $H \cap K$?  This should be the main part of the problem, but it seems you've just glossed over it by saying "In other words, $H \cap K$ has [...]"

Comment: @herbsteinberg $(G:K) = |\{gK : g \in G\}|$ is the cardinality of the set of left cosets.

Comment: @BrianMoehring What I thought was, those are the only ways to generate distinct cosets. If $g \in \overline{g_{k_i}}$ and $g \in \overline{g_{h_j}}$, then the coset produced is always the same.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Added an edit to my original proof. That might clarify the last part .

Comment: It's possible I'm just missing it, but I still don't see how exactly you're relating pairs of cosets of $H,K$ with cosets of $H\cap K$.  The simplest way I know to do this is to first show $g(H\cap K) = gH \cap gK$.  This gives an injection $$\{g(H\cap K) : g \in G\} \to \{gH : g \in G\} \times \{gK : g \in G\},$$ showing that $$(G : H\cap K) \leq (G:H) \cdot (G:K) < \infty.$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Your proof is more straightforward. I'll try that. I'll keep my proof up though. Hopefully someone can verify it. Also, I found a proof in here that appears to follow some of the arguments I've used if you're interested: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868383/problem-with-proof-of-h-cap-k-is-of-finite-index-if-h-k-are-finite-index?rq=1)

Comment: It would be better if instead of *obliterating* your previous work to which the comments refered, you simplly *added* the new material (with relevant added comments to indicate what you are doing). As it is, you've turned most of the comments in which you are relying appear to completely miss the point, as they refer to things that are no longer on the post.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Done. Put the original post back up.

Comment: Thank you. That's much better and useful for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This argument is, in spirit, closely related to the Third (or Second, depending how you number them) Isomorphism Theorem.

**Theorem.** $(H:H\cap K)\leq (G:K)$, in the sense of cardinality, with equality if $G=HK$. In the case where $(G:K)$ is finite, equality holds if and only if $HK=G$.

*Proof.* I claim that $h_1(H\cap K) = h_2(H\cap K)$ if and only if $h_1K = h_2K$. Indeed:
$$\begin{align*}
h_1K = h_2K &\iff h_2^{-1}h_1\in K\\
&\iff h_2^{-1}h_1\in H\cap K\\
&\iff h_1(H\cap K) = h_2(H\cap K).
\end{align*}$$
Thus, the map from $\{h(H\cap K)\mid h\in H\}$ to $\{gK\mid g\in G\}$ given by sending $h(H\cap K)$ to $hK$ is both well-defined and one-to-one. Thus, $(H:H\cap K)\leq (G:K)$ (in the sense of cardinality).

If $HK=G$, then every element of $\{gK\mid g\in G\}$ can be written as $hkK=hK$ for some $h\in H$, and thus the map above is a bijection, yielding equality. If $(G:K)$ is finite and we have equality, the injection above must be a bijection, and so every coset $gK$ is of the form $hK$ for some $h\in H$. Thus, given $g\in G$, there exists $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ such that $g=hk\in hK$, hence $G\subseteq HK$, which implies the equality. $\Box$

**Corollary.** $(G:H\cap K)\leq (G:H)(G:K)$ in the sense of cardinality.

*Proof.* $(G:H\cap K)= (G:H)(H:H\cap K) \leq (G:H)(G:K)$, in the sense or cardinality. $\Box$

**Corollary.** If $H$ and $K$ have finite index in $G$, then $H\cap K$ has finite index in $G$, and moreover $(G:H\cap K)\leq (G:H)(G:K)$, with equality if and only if $G=HK$.

*Proof.* The inequality was already proven. We get equality if and only if $(H:H\cap K)=(G:K)$, which holds in this situation if and only if $G=HK$. $\Box$

Why do I say it is related in spirit to the Third Isomorphism Theorem? That's the one that says that if $K$ is normal, then $HK/K$ is isomorphic to $H/H\cap K$. The bijection between these two is precisely the one that sends $h(H\cap K)$ to $hK$. If we knew $HK$ is a subgroup, we could show that $(HK:K)=(H:H\cap K)$, and then use that $HK\leq G$ to get $(H:H\cap K)\leq (G:K)$.