# A simple question involving groups and intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The context of the question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251467/if-h-k-g-and-gh-gk-are-finite-prove-g-h-cap-k-is-finite). In a conversation with my friend he had a doubt about why equality $g(H\cap K)=gH\cap gK$ is true . In my opinion it seemed to be trivial but I had a slight difficulty in constructing a raccion. So below is the idea I had to demonstrate that the equality is true. If I'm wrong or even unexplainable or if there is a simpler one to explain, leave your comment.

Initially I will prove that $g(H\cap K) \subseteq gH \cap gK$

Let $d \in g(H \cap K)$ be any element like this, we will have:

$gd$ , in which we notice that $gH$ and more is the elements of $H$ being multiplied by the factor $g$. Similarly we can apply the same for $gK$ as $d \in H$ and $d \in K$, so $gd \in gH$ and $gd \in gK= gH \cap gK$.

Prove $gH \cap gK \subseteq g(H\cap K)$

As we noted earlier, the $gH$ and $gK$ groups are simply the $H$ and $K$ groups, respectively, with their elements multiplied by the $g$ factor to their left.

So let $c \in gH \cap gK$, this element can be written being $gd$ this element can be written as $gd$ where $d \in H \cap K$, lastly $g(H\cap K)$.

So we conclude that  $g(H\cap K)=gH\cap gK$

(Note: I tried to explain with as much detail as possible my reasoning so that there are no doubts not only for whoever reads it but also for my friend since I intend to explain it this way to him.)

Comment: Use `$\subseteq$` for $\subseteq$.

Comment: This looks ok, if only a bit curt. You may want to note the straightforward generalization that if $a H$, $b K$ are two cosets of $H$, $K$, then either $a H \cap b K = \emptyset$, or $a H \cap b K$ is a coset of $H \cap K$.

Comment: If $c\in gH\cap gK$ then there exist $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ such that $c=gh=gk,$ implying $g^{-1}c=h=k\in K,$ but $h\in H$ too, so $h\in H\cap K.$ So $c=gh\in g (H\cap K). $Therefore $gH\cap gK\subset g(H\cap K).$